# Refresh page removes all cookies on SPA Blazor Wasm

Tags: azure, cookies, azure-functions, single-page-application, blazor-webassembly

I've made a client-server application in Blazor Wasm and Azure Functions Http triggered. The authentication is managed by cookies, so bearer and refresh token in http only secure cookies with same site property to false and some other cookies in not http only.

The application execution begins by making the authentication state check if user is logged or not. To do so the authentication state provider checks if a certain not http only cookie is present.
If not notifies an unauthorised state and show the login modal making the user logging in the login function, which returns refresh and bearer token into http only cookies and other infos into not http only cookies. Every authorized function check the consistency of http only cookies and permit the request if they are valid, otherwise returns 401.

In this moment on the page where the user lands there isn't an http request to functions, but the browser cookies and the requests seem right (see the following pictures). Cookies expiration is set to one week in the future.

[image]

[image]

The problem occurs while refreshing the page, because all cookies are removed from the browser. (pictures below)

[image]
[image]

As you can see there aren't any http requests.

Note that Blazor application and azure functions have different domains: https://x.y.azurestaticapps.net and https://z.azurewebsites.net.

Curiously when i try making the same process with both Blazor and functions in localhost, the cookies persist after refreshing the page. So the only different I can see between localhost run and deployed run is that the endpoints domains are differents. So where is the mistake? Doesn't it work on cross-site environment?

Even trying to make an http request after landing on the page, it seems that there is another request from the client to itself that stores other cookies and not mine ones.
Note that this request has cache-control: max-age=0

[image]

This request is different from localhost and azure also for the cookies stored inside: on localhost it contains all the cookies mentioned above

[image]

while the remote one has no cookies.

Comment: I have a similar problem as my auth authority is on a different domain, upon refresh all the cookies from that domain are erased. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Kiske1 I'm sorry, I've switched to a different solution. I've used azure b2c as identity server.